# SQLite is not able to save DateTimeOffSet value

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In our app the same update is executed in a SQL Server and a SQLite database.

The issue is that SQL Server works as expected however SQLite somehow is getting always 1/1/0001.

This is the update command:

```
UPDATE ReviewSow 
SET 
SowingDate = '7/1/2016 12:00:00 AM -03:00'
WHERE 
ReviewSowId = 3366;
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Why what could be happening, exactly? What is the table definition? What is the select query?

Comment: `ReviewSow` table definition is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983978/store-datetimeoffset-in-sqlite-net

Comment: This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Comment: I managed to solve this. The solution was very odd. When converting the date to ticks and passing as a string it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was rather odd. When converting the date to ticks and passing as a string it works perfectly! Strange but this is how SQLite works.

Example:

```
UPDATE ReviewSow SET SowingDate = '636263784001230000' WHERE ReviewSowId = 3366;
```

to convert DateTime to ticks:

```
((DateTimeOffset)value).Ticks.ToString()
```